# Wordpress PHP Function to convert PHP native timestamp to AEST

Tags: php

I have a wordpress site using Contact form 7 to collect leads (don't shoot me it's one i picked up from a previous developer) the leads are stored in a flamingo and then extracted using WP All Export and sent to our call centre for the agents to contact the leads.

During the extract process the date and time of the lead is stored in the flamingo record and through flamingo this is displayed correctly as (i assume) wordpress dictates the timezone and as such the UTC stored time is converted however when i export this from the system i am exporting the UTC timestamp which is of course a big difference from the UTC time.

I have an option to run a php function against the extract to reformat/manipulate data before it is exported but i am unable to put together a php script that works.

What i currently have is:

```
function updatedate($string) {
$date = new DateTime($string, strtotime(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney')));
return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
}
```

no doubt you'll look at the code, sigh and think **idiot**, which would be a fair assumption, I am by no means a php expert rather I muddle along learning as I go to achieve the outcome I need so any assistance you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: let me know if my answer is solution for you or if you have found a better solution post it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use strtotime here. as it will not work . new DateTimeZone() is an object  not a date/time string .

```
function updatedate($string) {
   $date = new DateTime($string, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
   return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
}
```